# Killing processes automatically - linux

Tags: linux, grep, kill-process

I al running this command :

```
pgrep -l someprocess
```

I get some outputs `XXXX someprocess`

then I kill every process appearing by hand, I would like to write a script to do it automatically, but this doesn(t make sense
 `kill -9 $(pgrep -l someprocess | grep "^[0-9]{4}")`

someone could help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use either `pkill` or `killall` to accomplish exactly that.

I found [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/4-ways-to-kill-a-process-kill-killall-pkill-xkill/) short and clear summary explaining the different ways of `kill`ing processes.

`pkill` is as simple as: `pkill someprocess`.

@ewm already included a detailed explanation about `killall` in his answer, so I'm not repeating it here.

Comment: Just by curiosity, if I had to write it by hand, how would I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at the 'killall' command:

KILLALL(1)                       User Commands                      KILLALL(1)

NAME
       killall - kill processes by name

SYNOPSIS
       killall [-Z,--context pattern] [-e,--exact] [-g,--process-group] [-i,--interactive] [-q,--quiet]
       [-r,--regexp] [-s,--signal signal] [-u,--user user] [-v,--verbose] [-w,--wait] [-I,--ignore-case]
       [-V,--version] [--] name ...
       killall -l
       killall -V,--version

DESCRIPTION
       killall  sends  a signal to all processes running any of the specified commands. If no signal name is
       specified, SIGTERM is sent.

```
   Signals can be specified either by name (e.g. -HUP or -SIGHUP ) or by number (e.g. -1) or  by  option
   -s.

   If the command name is not regular expression (option -r) and contains a slash (/), processes execut-
   ing that particular file will be selected for killing, independent of their name.

   killall returns a zero return code if at least one process has been killed for each  listed  command,
   or  no  commands  were listed and at least one process matched the -u and -Z search criteria. killall
   returns non-zero otherwise.

   A killall process never kills itself (but may kill other killall processes).
```

Comment: +1 `killall` is much more ubiquitous. Many platforms don't have `pkill`.  `sed`/`grep`, `ps`, and `kill` are also options.  `kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep [Tt]arget | sed -e 's/[A-Za-z]*  *\([0-9][0-9]*\).*/\1/')` will do in a pinch, but is much more brittle.